# Need help ID-ing this IC

Tags: integrated-circuit

[image: 14 pin IC]Trying to locate this IC. Hayward Power supply for a salt water pool control board. Tried Google & S-manuals.

Answer (score 10):

ST LM239 quad comparator in SO-14.

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm239.pdf

Comment: How did you know the "LM" part? "239" on its own seems like not much to go off of :p

Comment: @Alexander Years of experience + cheapest comparator you can buy so ubiquitous.

Comment: Thought it might be but it threw me because the ground pin is not connected to ground.

Comment: @RichL That’s certainly peculiar. Can you trace out where it goes?

Comment: Exactly what I thought, which is why I wasn't sure it was an LM239. The board is covered in urethane so it's a bit harder to see the traces and poke components but I will go back to it and see if I can track it down. The board has 2 voltages 24v & 12v. The 12v went missing and the fault seems to be in the area of the alleged LM239 IC. Actually I'm wondering if it may be that IC that is the fault. Perhaps it might be a TL series IC?

Comment: I find that termal camera is the fastest way to narrow down any offenders on faulty PCBs. There are ways to dissolve urethane conformal coating, or you can just probe though it with a sharp probe.